# How to append data in php file

Tags: javascript, php, json

Previously I'm using php to append form data into json file. Currently I am working on php file instead of json file and it  has two parameteres and it is shown to users as given in figure
[Image url link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te1ub.jpg)

My Form is

```html
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
 Name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <br><br/>
 Download Url:<br>
 <input type="text" name="downloadUrl">
 <br><br>
   

   
   
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My php file is

```html
{"downloadurl":[


{"name":"भाद्र ६ : LCR Series",
"downloadurl":"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1In76AN2Y5_qXV5ucXDXWx1PTKTTIvD3d"

},

{"name":"भाद्र ६ : LCR Parallel",
"downloadurl":"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1R9Ia4X12JZMsTn_vF6z443K6wKI2Rfeu"

}


]}
```

How can I use append new data  such that when submit button is clicked a new data is added on top of above php file such that new file will be

```html
    {"downloadurl":[


 {"name":"भाद्र ६ : New appended Data",
    "downloadurl":"This is new Text added on Top"

    },
    
    

    {"name":"भाद्र ६ : LCR Series",
    "downloadurl":"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1In76AN2Y5_qXV5ucXDXWx1PTKTTIvD3d"

    },

    {"name":"भाद्र ६ : LCR Parallel",
    "downloadurl":"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1R9Ia4X12JZMsTn_vF6z443K6wKI2Rfeu"

    }


    ]}
```

at top such that it will be displayed to user

Comment: Please share your code, what you have put here is not PHP, it is JSON.

Comment: What is the content of `process.php`?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher please check i have upload the file as .php here https://ibb.co/mRYEHU and it has same code as I have mentioned in above question.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher sorry I realized I have Json file inside php file...!! How can I add new data from form  in Json Data which is inside php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I think that this will solve your question. I'm using `array_unshift()` because your use of the phrase `on top` leads me to think that you would like to display the data before the existing data, if this is not correct, replace `array_unshift()` with `array_push()` so that it adds after the data, or see solution 2.

Solution 1:

```
<?php

    //This is where your JSON file is located
    $jsonFile = '/path/to/json/file';

    //Get the contents of your JSON file, and make it a useable array.
    $JSONString = json_decode( file_get_contents( $jsonFile ), true );

    //This is the new data that you want to add to your JSON
    $newData = array(
            //Your data goes here
        );

    //Add the new data to the start of your JSON
    array_unshift($existingData, $newData);

    //Encode the new array back to JSON
    $newData = json_encode( $existingData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

    //Put the JSON back into the file
    file_put_contents($jsonFile, $newData);

?>
```

Solution 2:

```
<?php

    //This is where your JSON file is located
    $jsonFile = '/path/to/json/file';

    //This is the new data that you want to add to your JSON
    $newData = array(
            //Your data goes here
        );

    //Encode the new data as JSON
    $newData = json_encode( $newData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

    //append the new data to the existing data
    file_put_contents( $jsonFile, $newData, FILE_APPEND );

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but my file is not json ..it is php file where data need to be added. I have again edited my question....please check.

Comment: What is your code? What you have posted above is not PHP, it is JSON

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to append text at the end of a PHP file, but you can use `file_put_contents()` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Comment: No I want to append text file in begigning such that new data will be displayed to user ..I have edited my question please check.